# 'Having' Clause in SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to execute a SQL query in python. The query works well in SQL, throws error in python. The query is used to find all the duplicates in 'Excel_Values' table

Query: 
`WITH duplicates AS (
   select    CaseID, ColumnName, TabType, ColumnValue, count(*) from [Excel_Values] 
   where Validation_Key= 52 
   group by  CaseID, ColumnName, TabType 
   having count(distinct ColumnValue) > 1
)
SELECT  a.*
FROM   [Excel_Values]  a
JOIN   duplicates b ON (a.CaseID = b.CaseID and a.ColumnName = b.ColumnName and a.TabType = b.TabType and a.Validation_Key = 52);`

Comment: Did you make use of a python-sql connector? You could also add the python code  you use to run the query and the resulting error. Thanks

Comment: Yes, when I run it on python I get the following error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "duplicates": syntax error